# How do I print a message after every new 10 values in sql using python?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

```
def read_from_db():
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM stuffToPlot')
    initial = 0
    data = c.fetchall()
    if len(data) - int(initial) == 20:
    print("New entries added")
    initial += 20


read_from_db()
```

`

I'm trying to print a message after every new 10 entries. But this one prints the message when I've 10 entries in total in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply try below:

```
def read_from_db():    
    try:
        c.execute('SELECT * FROM stuffToPlot')
        data=c.fetchall()
        for i in range(len(data)):
            if i%10==0:
               print ('New entries added')
            print(data[i])
    finally:
        c.close()

read_from_db()
```